# How to parse multiline child tag from XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, multiline

I try to parse an external XML in Python. There is Text tag (I changed the text here for clarification purposes) which suggests to be of multiple lines if the Multiline tag is greater than 0. I assume this as I have 25,000 Tags and can see that some end mid sentence. Every time they do the multiline tag is greater than zero. My question is now: how do I parse this as atm I will only see the text in the Text tag and not the other lines

```
<TAG>
<Surogat>253</Surogat>
<Number>3</Number>
<Date>20.02.2013</Date >
<Time>12:30</Time >
<Text>just for display purposes. The address of the place is: Merto</Text>
<Multiline>1</Multiline>
<Status>0</Status>
</TAG>
```

Im using:

```
for child in root.iter():
    print(child.tag, child.text.strip())
```

Which returns

```
Text just for display purposes. The address of the place is: Merto
Multiline 1
```

Comment: Can you calrify a bit? How is it "multiline"? I.e. what indicates a new line? And why does not your current core work, 'can you give example of input-xml and the output from your code?

Comment: @Cleared hope it is better now. I assume it is Multiline as the texts end mid sentence. I have downloaded the XML from an external source so I cannot answer what indicates a new line other than context

Comment: Can't you manually download the xml, open it in a text-editor and see what the actual content is? That would be help in solving your issue.